# Remove string from url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, strip

in my recent project, I need to remove some repeated characters from my url. More specific, I want to make this url

```
http://example.com/cgi-bin/file.cgi?ga_option1=a&ga_option2=b&ga_option3=c
```

become this, removed *ga_* part

```
http://example.com/cgi-bin/file.cgi?option1=a&option2=b&option3=c
```

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cgi-bin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)ga_(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1-$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

and this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cgi-bin/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "ga_" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://example.com/cgi-bin/file.cgi?$1 [R=301,L]
```

but nothing works. Please give me some advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /cgi-bin/file\.cgi\?ga_option1=a&ga_option2=b&ga_option3=c [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cgi-bin/file.cgi?option1=a&option2=b&option3=c [L,R]
```

If the query string is dynamic, then try this instead

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /cgi-bin/file\.cgi\?ga_option1=([^&]+)&ga_option2=([^&]+)&ga_option3=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?option1=%1&option2=%2&option3=%3 [L,R]
```

The reason why your #2 code isn't redirecting the request is because you are appending the uri to uri instead of the query string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but it did not work. I'm not sure but does it have something to do with RewriteBase rule?